# Conditional checkbox in Google Forms

Tags: google-forms

I'm creating a peer evaluation on Google Forms. The first question is for students to select their name. If the student has selected his/her name, the choice for his/her name will not appear in subsequent questions.
For example: 3 students Alex, Ben, and Cece. If Alex is the name selected from the first question, then for all subsequent questions, only 2 names Ben and Cece will appear.
I tried googling this but nothing seems to be what I'm looking for. Appreciate if anyone can suggest a way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

It could be possible to remove the options after the form response is submitted not based on selections made on previous questions on unsubmitted form responses.

The alternative is change the design of your form or use another app like Google Apps Script to build your form by using the HTML Service which implies that you should know about HTML/CSS/JavaScript and learn about Client-Server communication between the form and the related script project.